# Missing files for `magic` library on Windows

Tags: python, windows, gnuwin32, python-magic

I need to get mime type for some files on windows, so i've installed `python-magic` (on 32-bit python 2.7.3).
It depends on unix `magic` library.
Author instructs to get `regex2.dll`, `zlib1.dll` and `magic1.dll` from gnuwin32 project.
So i saved the files to a folder and added the folder to my system `PATH`.
Now when i execute `magic` methods, i get missing file exception:

```
import magic
print(magic.Magic())

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/lex/lex.py", line 367, in <module>
  test_magic()
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/lex/lex.py", line 364, in test_magic
  print(magic.Magic())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.3-py2.7.egg\magic.py", line 52, in __init__
  magic_load(self.cookie, magic_file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.3-py2.7.egg\magic.py", line 188, in magic_load
  return _magic_load(cookie, coerce_filename(filename))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_magic-0.4.3-py2.7.egg\magic.py", line 139, in errorcheck
  raise MagicException(err)
magic.MagicException: could not find any magic files!
```

DLLs are in the PATH, i tried debugging and `magic1.dll` is located correctly, but somewhere inside library throws an exception.
Inside the `gnuwin32` package i've found `magic` and `magic.mgc`. I placed them to the same folder, and got `WindowsError: [Error 126]` on

```
libmagic = None  
# Let's try to find magic or magic1  
dll = ctypes.util.find_library('magic') or ctypes.util.find_library('magic1')  

# This is necessary because find_library returns None if it doesn't find the library
if dll:
    libmagic = ctypes.CDLL(dll)
```

This obviously happens because python tries to open `magic` file as dll, which is plain text. After adding `.dll` to filenames in the code i get the same `magic.MagicException: could not find any magic files!`.
What files am i missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
C:\Users\Admin>file C:\123.zip -m magic
file: could not find any magic files!

C:\Users\Admin>file C:\123.zip -m "C:\@DEV\@LIB\@Magic\GetGnuWin32\bin\magic"
C:\123.zip; ASCII text, with no line terminators

C:\Users\Admin>cd C:\@DEV\@LIB\@Magic\GetGnuWin32\bin

C:\@DEV\@LIB\@Magic\GetGnuWin32\bin>file C:\123.zip -m magic
C:\123.zip; ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

**UPDATE 2 (SOLVED):**

```
print(magic.Magic())
magic.MagicException: could not find any magic files!

print(magic.Magic(magic_file = 'magic'))
<magic.Magic instance at 0x02A5E198>
```

just had to specify file explicitly

Comment: Stupid question, have you restarted the command prompt AFTER you've added the DLL's to the `PATH` and BEFORE you executed the script? (silly question, since you obviously know your way around ctypes)

Comment: "have you restarted the command prompt AFTER you've added the DLL's to the PATH" - 
yes, i did

Comment: Tried placing the dll's in the same directory and try ctypes on those? or if that might help to begin with? I don't know if they're looking for the DLL's at a specific place such as `./` but it might be good just to try? - Crap, just re-read the question.. you already did.. (i'm tired, 00:00 AM here)

Comment: Have tried placing in the same directory with my script - all the same.

Comment: Does this help: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802350-module-python-magic-windows (specificly the part about the folder names in which the DLL's should be placed)

Comment: I've tried share, share/file, file, file/share, file/share/file and c:/program files/file/share/file/ directories. None of it helped.

Comment: Tried using the -m param on Python when starting the script and get the module import type and a better verbosity of what's happening? `Python -h` for more param options but they can give you a better trace of what it's trying to import and where, hopefully you can corelate that with why the DLL's appear to be missing..

Comment: Please answer your question, if I am following your last update you were missing the actual "magic" file/lookup table of mime-types to suffixs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path to `magic` file has to be explicitly passed to the constructor.

```
magic_object = magic.Magic(magic_file = 'path_to_magic_files/magic'))
```

Comment: @picomon perfect questions. people with limited communication skills tend to forget mentioning such details

Answer (score 11):

For future google visitors: Another solution is setting the %MAGIC% enviroment variable in the systems setting to point to the magic file, for me it was:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\misc\magic"
```

No need to hardcode the path in your program!

Answer (score 2):

As the python-magic problems seems to be quite common, here a working solution fo future googlers:
After testing most solutions without altering the source-code, I found the following to get python-magic working out of the box:

1. Install [GnuWin32 file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) ***first***
2. Set the environment variable MAGIC=path\to\gnuwin32\share\misc\magic
3. Assure all installed executables/libraries to be accessible via the
   PATH
4. Install python-magic via pip

Answer (score 2):

Please try install this package:

```
pip install python-magic-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

try this：

```
pip uninstall python-magic
pip uninstall python-magic-bin
pip install python-magic
pip install python-magic-bin
```

which means install python-magic-bin after python-magic

reference：https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/248