# Python Error : File 5.3 supports only version 7 magic file

Tags: python, windows, python-magic

I installed python-magic with magic1.dll, regex2.dll, and zlib1.dll files and it imports correctly but when I try to do for example `m = magic.Magic()` I get the error : `Could not find any magic file`.So, I googled a little bit and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761961/missing-files-for-magic-library-on-windows) that gave me another error : `File 5.3 supports only version 7 magic file. "magic.mgc" is version 12.`

Can I get a magic file version 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot for a solution for this problem, but couldn't found. I was a little bit playing with magic files and suddenly it worked. So now I will write a step-by-step to resolve problems like mine or similar to mine for Windows and Linux Users.

**FOR WINDOWS:**

**Step 1:** Delete the `magic.py` and the `magic.pyc` files from your python lib folder. And if you downloaded `zlib1.dll`, `magic1.dll`, `regex2.dll` and `magic.mgc`, also delete them.

**Step 2:** Download [this zip file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/s027ckiq9tdw6rl/Files_For_Python-Magic.zip) and extract it.

***Note :*** *This zip file contains all what we need : `magic.py` ,`magic.pyc`, `magic.mgc`, `zlib1.dll`, `magic.dll` and `regex2.dll`.*

**Step 3:** Then move `magic.py` ,`magic.pyc` and the DLL files to the python lib folder.

**Step 4:** Go to Computer Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables, and click on `New...`. In the variable name type : `magic` And in the other field enter the path to the `magic.mgc` file and press Ok.

*And Now It Should Work:*

```
>>> import magic
>>> s = magic.Magic()
>>> s.from_file("test.txt")
'ASCII text, with no line terminators'
>>>
```

***Note :*** *If you compile your program to EXE, make sure that the DLL files and `magic.mgc` are in the same folder as your EXE program to work properly. If you don't do that you will get errors*

---

**FOR LINUX:**

If you are a Linux user and you have problems with magic, here are what you have to do:

**Step 1:** In your command line, type `sudo pip install python-magic` to install or to upgrade to the lastest version of python-magic. If you have the `IncompleteRead` error, then type in your command line:

For Python 2:

> sudo apt-get remove python-pip && sudo easy_install pip

For Python 3:

> sudo apt-get remove python3-pip && sudo easy_install3 pip

This will upgrade in a certain way your pip and remove the error. After it finished, type `sudo pip install python-magic` to install magic after the pip upgrade.

*Then It should Work:*

```
>>> import magic
>>> s = magic.Magic()
>>> s.from_file("test.txt")
'ASCII text, with no line terminators'
>>>
```

Comment: i did what ever u mentioned in the post still i am getting this error`magic.MagicException: File 5.20 supports only version 12 magic files. `C:\Python27\Lib\magic.mgc' is version 7`. I am using python2.7,12 in windows 10 64 bit virtual box. Help me ASAP..!!