# Python-Magic 'could not find any valid magic files!'

Tags: python, python-magic

I want to use `Python-Magic` library, but I get:

> magic.magic.MagicException: b'could not find any valid magic files!'

Error on a simple code like this:

```
filepath = 'path\\somefile.txt'
print(magic.from_file(filepath))
```

I did google the error message and I tried this; as mentioned [Missing files for `magic` library on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761961/missing-files-for-magic-library-on-windows)

```
magic_object = magic.Magic(magic_file = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\share\\misc\\magic')
```

This time I get this error:

> magic.magic.MagicException: b"File 5.32 supports only version 14 magic files. `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\share\misc\magic.mgc' is version 7"

I also did this; [Python Error : File 5.3 supports only version 7 magic file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390318/python-error-file-5-3-supports-only-version-7-magic-file) nothing changes.

Also I tried changing environment variable`MAGIC=path\to\gnuwin32\share\misc\magic` and downloading http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm and nothing changes.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This may not be your problem, but [never use unescaped backslashes in non-raw string literals for Windows pathnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

Comment: @abarnert I actually use  'os.path' and it works for other lines of codes.

Comment: change the path to some other literal path with `\test` in it you'll see the issue.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by that, but unescaped backslashes in pathname strings are wrong before it even gets to `os.path`. For example, the string `’\b’` is a single backspace, not a backslash and a `b`.  With many letters you will get lucky, but you shouldn’t rely on getting lucky. Just escape them, use a raw string literal, or use forward slashes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you mean like `C:\Users\MertTheGreat\Desktop\somefile.txt` because the path is something like that.

Comment: `\U` will fail in python 3 (unicode escape).